# How to delete model by filtering with pk

Tags: python, django, django-models, slug

I am trying to delete an entire model using pk, but when I click on "delete" I am redirected to the given page but nothing happens model is still there and not being deleted, but when I write the 'room_name' instead of 'pk' it does work, (thanks in advance)

```
*Views.py:
def delete_room(request, pk):
    Room.objects.filter(name=pk).delete()
    return redirect('home')

Urls.py:
    path("delete/<int:pk>/", views.delete_room, name="delete_room")

Models.py:
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='room_creator')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="RoomMember")
    
    
class RoomMember(models.Model):
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name='memberships', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_groups', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
        
class Messages(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=False, null=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Html:
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete_room' pk=room.pk %}">Delete Room</a>*
```

Comment: I think you need `Room.objects.filter(pk=pk).delete()`

Comment: GREAT! it worked thanks a lot man

Comment: small write-error here, what your trying is not called a `model`, it is a `model instance`, remember whatever you have as a model in your models converts to a full table in SQL, so are trying to delete a full table or one instance? Just collecting you on that but what @voodoo-burger has commented is totally right!

Comment: @JetEzra thanks for the correction. So I had  a Model named room and I was trying to delete just 1 room (the current room where user see the delete button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter on the primary key `pk` of the item, so:

```
def delete_room(request, pk):
    Room.objects.filter(pk=pk).delete()
    return redirect('home')
```

But you should *not* do this for a GET request. Removing items should be done through a POST request or a DELETE request. [As the W3 organization says](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1):

> In particular, the convention has been established that the **GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval**. These **methods ought to be considered “safe”**.

If you accept GET requests, search engines, and some browsers that already retrieve links of a page, might accidentally visit that view, and thus accidentally remove data.

You thus should limit the HTTP methods with:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(['DELETE', 'POST'])
def delete_room(request, pk):
    Room.objects.filter(pk=pk).delete()
    return redirect('home')
```

For the HTML you should make a mini form like:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'delete_room' pk=room.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Room</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Whereas @Willem's answer is totally fine, I can also show you a simpler and beginner friendly way of handling request methods from the request object.

```py
def delete_room(request):
    if request.method == "POST" or request.method == "DELETE":
        #Handle your post and delete requests here
        #e.g, deleting as was in the question
        Room.objects.filter(pk=pk).delete()
        #user will never get in here unless they hit via .delete or .post 
        #requests
    return redirect('home')
```